# How to send a regex through another regex match without any affection

Tags: regex, perl

I use below perl code to split a given string by comma or space in general. I also need to pass a regex content,but that regex getting wrong.

```
sub specificStrChecker
{
    my $input_line = shift;
    my @specificStrs = split(/[,\s]+/, $input_line);
    print "----------------------------\n";
    foreach (@specificStrs) # list of perl regex | normal str
    {
        print "$_\n";
    }
    print "----------------------------\n\n";
}

my $str_1 = "abc,pqr";
my $str_2 = "/ {2,}/, ghi"; # i need to print / {2,}/

specificStrChecker($str_1);
specificStrChecker($str_2); # i need to print / {2,}/
```

Output :

---

abc

pqr

---

---

/

{2

}/

ghi

---

In above second part, i need "/ {2,}/" but here it affects with the split regex. How do i avoid that.?

Comment: What is your input string ?

Comment: I hard coded it into $str_1 and $str-2 . Regex in $str_2. (/ {2,}/)

Comment: try [quotemeta] (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta.html)

if you want to strip **ghi** approach would be different. 

If you want to find how to find any string between two slash that would a whole new approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your regexes don't contain any `/` characters, this is simply changing your split to instead match a series of /-delimited substrings or strings of non-comma, non-whitespace characters:

```
my @specificStrs = $input_line =~ m{(/[^/]*/|[^,\s]+)}g;
```

Comment: thanks ysth.! And, i need to remove that regex from another string. Eg:  $str_new =~s/($_)//g; # where $_ = / {2,}/ or a normal string like 'abc'. But, that is not work for / {2,}/. How can i remove only start and end characters which is mapped to '/'.

Comment: @yasaramalshan you should ask a separate question for that, showing what your data is and expected results and anything you've tried